# Problema con singleton pattern Nodejs y MySql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mysqlconnector, singleton

recurro a Uds para ver si me pueden ayudar, ya que estoy tratando de implementar un singleton pattern con node, pero tengo un problema ya que no puedo generar la conexión correspondiente con instance, si me pueden guiar en lo que tengo que cambiar o dentro de mi codigo,
desde ya muchas gracias

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


class Mysql {

constructor() {

    if (this.instance) {
        return this.instance;
    }

    this.conexion = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'cerveza',
        port: '3306'
    });

    this.conectarDB();

    this.instance = this;
}


static conectarDB() {
   this.conexion.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        this.conectado = true;
        console.log('Base de datos conectado');
    });
}

static ejecutarQuery(query, callback) {

    this.instance.conexion.query(query, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error en el query");
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err);
        }

        if (results.length === 0) {
            callback('El registro solicitado no existe');
        } else {
            callback(null, results);
        }
    });
}

}


module.exports = {
    Mysql
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]